# C# Gecko Turn off Hardware Acceleration

Tags: c#, hardware-acceleration, geckofx

I have some problems with playing youtube videos (jerky) by using Gecko. I think that problem can be solved by turn off "hardware accessleration". I don't know how to do it. This is setting code:

```
GeckoPreferences.User["browser.xul.error_pages.enabled"] = false;
string appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\";
Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(appPath + "firefox");
```

Please help me. Sorry about my English. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set these options:

```
gfx.direct2d.disabled = true
```

and

```
layers.acceleration.disabled = true
```

([Reference](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-hardware-acceleration-gpu-rendering-in-mozilla-firefox-4-0-to-fix-font-problem/))

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but the youtube video is still jerky. Do you know which option that force the Firefox use flash instead of html5, thanks.

Comment: `media.mediasource.youtubeonly = false`